# DRF use nested serializer to create key object instead of array

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

### Context

Say we take this example from the [DRF relations guide](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/).

```
# models.py
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('album', 'order')
        ordering = ['order']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%d: %s' % (self.order, self.title)
```

Using a serializer will get us this output

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

Will get us this output:

```
{
    'album_name': 'Things We Lost In The Fire',
    'artist': 'Low',
    'tracks': [
        '1: Sunflower',
        '2: Whitetail',
        '3: Dinosaur Act',
        ...
    ]
}
```

### Question

How can i use the serializer to get the output like this:

```
  {
    'album_name': 'Things We Lost In The Fire',
    'artist': 'Low',
    'tracks': {
        1: {order: 1, title: 'Sunflower'},
        2: {order:2, title: 'Whitetail'},
        3: {order:3, title: 'Dinosaur Act'},
        ...
    }
}
```

This way we have an object with tracks instead of a numeric array. So i can do `this.props.album.tracks[2].title` this instead of `this.props.album.tracks.find(track => track.order == 2}).title` in javascript.

``I have an use case in where this seems to be more convenient in Reactjs.

#### What i have tried

I thought about overriding the `to_representation` method. But i see that this will get me an recursive loop.

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        print(self)
        return '%s: { %s }' % (instance.order, self.to_representation(instance))
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Track
```

Furthermore i have searched and read the docs pretty well. But didn't find any solution for what i think should be a pretty logical solution to have out of the box. Making me think that i am wrong and missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new **`TrackSerializer`** and use it in **`AlbumSerializer`** class as,

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('id', 'order', 'title')


class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['tracks'] = {track['id']: track for track in representation['tracks']}
        return representation
```

Comment: This is what i have already have. But this will get met an array/list of tracks in the Album object. However i want a object of tracks instead. So i can acces a track directly by using a order number. I have updated my question :)

Comment: Override the **`to_representation()`** method of the `AlbumSerializer` , check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks! This is working fine. However i would like to be able to update tracks from album endpoint. Of course it will get me `Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"`. I tried a workaround but the request is ignored anyway.  I created another question for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56868385/update-nested-serializer-with-an-overwritten-to-representation