# Update nested serializer with an overwritten to_representation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

#### Context

So i have an `AlbumSerializer` with a nested `TrackSerializer`. For convenience on the frontend I overwrite the representation of `AlbumSerializer` to make a dictionary of the tracks instead of a list.

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('id', 'order', 'title')
    # directly upsert tracks
    def create(self, validated_data):
            obj, created = Track.objects.update_or_create(
            album_id= validated_data['album_id'],
            order=validated_data['order'],
            defaults={'title': validated_data['title']}
            )
            return obj


class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')

    # make a dictionary of the tracks
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['tracks'] = {track['id']: track for track in representation['tracks']}
        return representation

    #update tracks with the album endpoint
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for track in validated_data['tracks']
            obj, created = Track.objects.update_or_create(
            album_id= track['album_id'],
            order=track['order'],
            defaults={'title': track['title']}
            )
        return instance
```

#### Problem

Now when i try to update the album, including some track titles, i receive `Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"`. Which makes sense.

#### Question

How can i make DRF accept dictionaries instead of a list if tracks ?

**Update:** Just learned about [`drf-rw-serializers`](https://www.vinta.com.br/blog/2018/django-rest-framework-read-write-serializers/). Seems exactly what i need.

Comment: why are you using `return obj` inside `forloop`?

Comment: Thanks! Did some copy pasting. Edited the post. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

in update function, you are:

- trying to loop a dictionary like a list
- using update_or_create, this will lead to create duplicate tracks

Here is an error fixed code::

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    for trackid, track in validated_data['tracks'].items():
        obj = Track.objects.filter(id = trackid)
        if obj:
            obj[0].album_id = track['album_id']
            obj[0].order = track['order']
            obj[0].title = title= track['title']
            obj[0].save()
        else:
            Track.objects.create(
                album_id= track['album_id'],
                order=track['order'],  
                title= track['title'])
    return instance
```

Comment: Thank you! But you are one step ahead: This will not prevent the error `"Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"."`.