# DRF: many=True causes array instead of returning a regular object

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using a nested serializer to access the facility address of each facility.
The only way the values will actually show is when i add many=true to the "LeadFacilityDetailFacilitySerializer".
But the issue is that it will add [] around my address object.
Which leads to "undefined" whjen i try to access the items inside my address object:

```
{info.LeadFacilityDetailFacility.AddressInfo.City}
```

serializers.py

```
class LeadAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FacilityAddress
        fields = (
            "PrimaryAddress",
            "SecondaryAddress",
            "City",
            "RegionOrState",
            "PostalCode",
        )

class LeadFacilityDetailFacilitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    AddressInfo = LeadAddressSerializer(source="fa", many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Facility
        fields = ('mainimage', 'Name', 'AdministratorCell', 'AddressInfo')


class LeadFacilityDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    LeadFacilityDetailFacility = LeadFacilityDetailFacilitySerializer(source="assigned_facilities")    

    class Meta:
        model = LeadFacilityAssign
        fields = ('assigned_facilities', 'datetime', 'id', 'LeadFacilityDetailFacility')
```

models.py

```
class FacilityAddress(models.Model):
    PrimaryAddress = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    SecondaryAddress = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    City = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    RegionOrState = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    PostalCode = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    Geolocation = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    AddressInfo = models.ForeignKey(Facility, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fa')

class Facility(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=False)
```

## Update:

I found this answer [DRF use nested serializer to create key object instead of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56836737/drf-use-nested-serializer-to-create-key-object-instead-of-array) but it seems to add the id of the object in front of the bracket of the address object.

```
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['AddressInfo'] = {FacilityAddress["id"]: FacilityAddress for FacilityAddress in representation['AddressInfo']}
        return representation
```

Comment: why dont you use `many=False` then

Comment: Because that will return null on all the address items.

Comment: *The only way the values will actually show is when i add `many=True`* - becouse you're using **OneToMany** relation eg. `AddressInfo = models.ForeignKey(...)` that's why you've to pass `many=True` if you don't want that then use **OneToOne** relation.

Comment: unfortunately that is not an option